# Maven not discovering ScalaTest unit tests

Tags: scala, maven, scalatest, scalatest-maven-plugin

I have the following unit tests:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSpec
import org.scalatest.Matchers._

class MyClassSpec extends FunSpec {

  describe("MyClass"){
    describe("Scenario 1"){
      it("Condition 1") {
        true shouldEqual false
      }

      it("Condition 2"){
        true shouldEqual false
      }
    }
  }

}
```

When I run maven test, this compiles fine but the tests are not found. Here is the output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7:test (default-test) @ project-name ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scalatest-maven-plugin:1.0:test (test) @ project-name ---
Discovery starting.
Discovery completed in 202 milliseconds.
Run starting. Expected test count is: 0
DiscoverySuite:
Run completed in 236 milliseconds.
Total number of tests run: 0
Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
No tests were executed.
```

As the output shows, I'm using the scalatest plugin for maven. Here is the relevant section of my pom.xml:

```
<!-- disable surefire -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<!-- enable scalatest -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/scalatest-reports</reportsDirectory>
        <junitxml>junit</junitxml>
        <filereports>report.txt</filereports>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I'm pretty new to getting this stuff set up, so I'm not sure if there is some other thing I'm not checking. I get the exact same results if I run maven clean and then maven test. I'm using ScalaTest version 3.0.1. I have another project with tests running successfully also using 3.0.1 (I've copied everything I can find between the two projects that seems even remotely related).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally, the problem seems to have stemmed from some information I didn't think was relevant, so I didn't include it my original post.

The source code I wrote was a tool for unit testing, so I put it in the namespace `my.cool.package.testUtilities`. The unit tests were thus in `my.cool.package.testUtilities.test`. Moving the source code out of `testUtilities` (to just `my.cool.package`) and moving the tests to just `my.cool.package.test` allowed the tests to be discovered.

Being new to the java ecosystem (previous experience in .NET), I'm not sure if this is some weird bug with the test runner, expected behavior, or if the act of moving the files to new namespaces did something else, and the namespaces themselves are irrelevant. So I'm not sure what I learned from this.

Answer (score 0):

You have placed `<skipTest> true </skipTest>` which is used for skipping the test cases. So basically you have disabled the surefire and it is used for:

> The Surefire Plugin is used during the test phase of the build
>   lifecycle to execute the unit tests of an application. It generates
>   reports in two different file formats Plain text files (.txt) XML
>   files (.xml)

Update your pom with:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
       <useFile>false</useFile>
       <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
       <!-- If you have classpath issue like NoDefClassError,...-->
       <!-- useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar -->
       <includes>
           <include>**/*Test.*</include>
            <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
            <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
       </includes>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In **include** you have to provide the extension of your test file and you can change the version of pluggin.

Thanks

Comment: This change would require all tests to be annotated instead of using `scalatest-maven-plugin`. I know the maven plugin works because another project is able to find tests successfully.

Comment: In that case, you have to check your all setting because there should be a different setting in pom or if possible you can share the settings so that we can look.

Comment: I have what I think is the relevant section of the `pom.xml` in the post - is there another section you want to see? Is there another file that could contain some relevant information?