# Maven not discovering Scala tests

Tags: maven, scalatest

I am new to maven and trying to make it work with ScalaTest.
In my pom.xml, I disabled sunfire and enabled the maven scala test plugin. (As in the link below)

I also put the tags for sourceDirectory and testSourceDirectory

```
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
```

Here are my folders:

```
src
 - main
   - scala
     - lot.of.packages
       - utility
         * ClassName
 - test
   - scala
     - lot.of.packages
       - utility
         * ClassNameTest
```

I am trying to run the tests with `mvn test`

The problem is that Maven does not discover the tests.

```
Discovery starting.
Discovery completed in 272 milliseconds.
Run starting. Expected test count is: 0
```

The strangest thing is if I run manually the test in the ide (Intellij), then it does discover the test with mvn after.

But if I add a new test, once again it does not discover the new test (might be a cache problem?)

I already looked there, but I did not find any answer [Maven not discovering ScalaTest unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268060/maven-not-discovering-scalatest-unit-tests)

If there is any information missing, comment below I will add them

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.1.6` plugin, adding `<goal>testCompile</goal>`in the compile execution phase is a workaround, not the solution but good enough for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the configuration of maven-surefire-plugin ?
The default includes of this plugin are

```
<includes>
    <include>**/Test*.java</include>
    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
    <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

Check the officiial documentation : https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

Comment: I actually disabled surefire, to use the scala test maven plugin. But you are answer might be the beginning of an answer (use the tags includes in the scala test plugin) I am going to check how to use it